# WKWebView not showing Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, wkwebview

I have a view in SwiftUI that shows a `WKWebView` which is passed to the main ContentView using the `UIViewControllerRepresentable` class, implemented following the instructions from [Paul Huson's 'Creating a simple browser with WKWebView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=578&v=pLiT5DdjEbM&feature=emb_logo). However, when I load the app in the simulator, there doesn't seem to be a Navigation Bar.

Here is my code:

The `ContentView` and `BrowserView`

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let browserView = BrowserView()
    var body: some View {
        browserView
    }
}

struct BrowserView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<BrowserView>) -> WKBrowser {
        let browser = WKBrowser()
        return browser
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: WKBrowser, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<BrowserView>) {
        // Empty
    }

}
```

The `WKBrowser` class

```
class WKBrowser: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    var webURL = URL(string: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com")!

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView?.navigationDelegate = self
        self.view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: webURL))
    }
}
```

The result:

[image: The WKWebView]

Compared to the WKWebView from the tutorial which has the Navigation Bar and looks like this:

[image]

What do I have to add or edit in order to ensure the Navigation Bar appears?

Edit 05/19/2020:

I'd like to add items to the navigation bar via the `navigationItem.rightBarItem` function, added to the `viewDidLoad`, like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: webURL))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Open", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(someFunction)
}

@objc func someFunction(){
    // Do something
}
```

Optimally, the result would look something similar to `SFSafariViewController`:

[image]

But when when I wrap the `UIViewRepresentable` class in a `NavigationView`, these items are not added to the Navigation Bar that appears, and I instead get this:

[image]

Comment: Why do you needed it? Anyway, put into NavigationView if you want or in UINavigationController at representable side in usual way.

Comment: Please see the edit to my question. I would like to use the `navigation.rightBarItem` function in `viewDidLoad`, and putting the `browserView` inside a NavigationView doesn't allow me to add items to the navigation bar that appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to work with navigation bar in UIKit part then you need to wrap your UIKit browser in `UINavigationController`, like below

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```
struct BrowserView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController {
        let browser = WKBrowser()
        return UINavigationController(rootViewController: browser)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UINavigationController, context: Context) {
        // Empty
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

actually you have a simpler way.

first wrap a web view:

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var url: URL
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }
}
```

then you can put the WebView into a VStack and this will make the UIView stuff like a SwiftUI component. and everything work fine!

```
   var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                WebView(url: someURL)
            }
            .toolbar {
               // buttons here ....
            }
        }
   }
```

Great!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Xcode 14 while following the same tutorial. Embedding in Navigation Controller solved the problem without changing any of the code from the tutorial.

Comment: This worked! I'm learning with HackingWithSwift but the tutorial has not mentioned this problem.